# Taking forever to move files to the trash

Tags: finder, filesystem, trash

Finder is taking forever to move, rename, etc. files, especially when moving to the trash or emptying the trash.

Here is a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xI1jlh8d6C0&feature=youtube_gdata_player

It takes 80-95% of my CPU and spins 13 threads to think about it for a few minutes:
[image]
[image]

About my Mac:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you move the folder elsewhere in the filesystem instead of moving the files to the Trash, does it also need a long time? Does the folder reside on a external hard drive? How full is the hard drive where the folder is located?

Comment: Sometimes yes. No externals connected. 12GB remaining.

Comment: I don't understand the disconnect between the `% CPU` column data and the data at the bottom of the window, both numbers and graph.

Comment: How old is the system you are working with? Was it a fresh 10.8 install or have you updated your OS for years? I'm thinking directory data corruption.

Comment: This is a brand new retina mbp

Comment: Video of the problem added

Comment: @Josh The `% CPU` column shows a per-core percentage, while the graph is an aggregate of all cores.

Comment: @KirkStrobeck Check out [XBench](http://www.xbench.com/) and see how you stack up. The drive may be doing strange things, possibly a dud controller or some such thing. Also, HDD or SSD?

Comment: @alexandru, thanks for the clarification... that makes sense.

Comment: How large is the folder and how many files are contained within? Folders with lots of files (>500) can take a while to process prior to deleting--both when moving to the trash and emptying the trash.

Comment: I see this all the time on my MacBook Pro running 10.8.x. I suspect it's due to HDDs and sloppy, inefficient coding in Mountain Lion. This is up to Apple to fix. I never saw this behaviour in the 10.6 Finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I took it to the Apple store, they weren't really any help. I held down `option` and reinstalled the OS in-place and that worked! Finally I can use Finder again .. whew! Let me know if this helped you.

Comment: Great if it worked for you. I assume manually clearing out the trash via Terminal (`rm -rf ~/.Trash`) wasn't helpful?

Comment: I'm not sure .. I never tried it. I went with the advice from the Apple Store

Comment: FWIW, I've seen this problem in Big Sur … and now in Monterey on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro. The workaround is to restart my machine.